# session problems on mamp

Tags: session, mamp

I have a problem with sessions, my php code works perfectly on easyPhp but not on MAMP. 
With easyPhp I have to modify the php.ini file from session.auto_start = 0 to  session.auto_start = 1.
What should I do to make it work with MAMP?

Answer (score 4):

For MAMP, the default php.ini setting is `session.auto_start = 0`. So I'm assuming you wish to modify it to `session.auto_start = 1` as you did for easyPHP.

In order to do so, follow these steps:

1. Start MAMP
2. File > Edit Template > PHP > [select php.ini file]*
3. Find the line that says: `session.auto_start = 0`
4. Change it to `session.auto_start = 1`
5. Save the file
6. Restart your MAMP server

Once you change any of the MAMP configuration defaults, MAMP will generate an appropriate configuration file in the following subdirectory: `~/Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/templates/`, so you can edit those files directly, instead of going through MAMP.

* The php.ini file you select should match the version you're running through MAMP (selected under server > PHP, in the main window).